# Time series forecasting with a variable

Tags: r

I have my data as below:

I have Date, Category and Qty in my data, where Category has n different types.

I'm able to forecast Qty, using just Date, but I would want to include Category in the forecast, so I do not have to load n different files to separate one category at a time.
I'm new to R and any guidance is highly appreciated.
Please advise.

[image]

Comment: 1) Please don't share data as an image, but use e.g. `dput` instead. 2) Please share the code you have so far.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide your data in a reproducible format and share more information about the problem, such as what you tried and where you are stuck. Have a look at [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/5892059)

Comment: Y <- ts(df[,2], start = c(2019,2), frequency = 330)
fit_arima <- auto.arima(Y,d=1, stepwise = FALSE, approximation = FALSE, trace = TRUE)
print(summary(fit_arima)) 
checkresiduals(fit_arima)
fcst <- forecast(fit_arima, h=7)
autoplot(fcst)
print(summary(fcst))

How do i use Category variable as an input in this code?

Comment: I'm pretty new to R and any help is highly appreciated